# Insert a set of values in a range in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a range selected and I want to insert some values in it

This is the code I have tried to put up

```
// I got this a5_range by offsetting from another reference cell
var a5_range = a1_range.offset(0,13);
a5_range = a5_range.offset(0,1,15,8);
a5_range.setBackground("#e6e6e6").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
const p_perc = ["40%", "20%", "30%", "21%", "35%", "28%", "25%", "13%"];
// code to include above value in a5_range
a5_range.setNumberFormat("[$$]#,##0.00");
```

below is the output I want for `a5_range`

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function elfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const a1_range = sh.getRange("A1");//initialize to something
  var a5_range = a1_range.offset(0, 13);
  a5_range = a5_range.offset(0, 1, 15, 8);
  a5_range.setBackground("#e6e6e6").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  const p_perc = ["40%", "20%", "30%", "21%", "35%", "28%", "25%", "13%"];
  a5_range.setNumberFormat("[$$]#,##0.00");
  a5_range.setValues([...Array.from(new Array(a5_range.getHeight()).keys(),x => p_perc)]);
}
```

Demo:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |
| 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40% | 20% | 30% | 21% | 35% | 28% | 25% | 13% |

Image:

[image]

Comment: this works like a charm, could you please help me understand this ```[...Array.from(new Array(a5_range.getHeight()).keys(),x => p_perc)])```. you are creating an array and getting the number of rows in the range with "getHeight", whats with .keys() and x => p_perc

Comment: Have you ever use Array.from? or new Array()?

Comment: What does object.keys() return if the object is an array of a5_range.getHeight() length?

Comment: `[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(x => [p_perc];]`